# Flex item not aligning its content to the right

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have the following HTML where I would like to right align the contents of the right flex item:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex">
    <div class="flex-grow-1">
        Line 1
        <br />Line 2
    </div>
    <div class="ml-auto">
        <strong>Line 3</strong><br/>
        Longer line 4
    </div>
</div>
```

However, the contents are not being right-aligned. ie. The text `Line 3` and `Longer line 4` should be right-aligned.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please share some details about what the desired output should look like. Also, show us what you are currently getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*use* class="text-right"

```
<div class="text-right">
   <strong>Line 3</strong><br/>
    Longer line 4
</div>
```